# Lyapunov function, weak

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I got some trouble with a problem about Lyapunov functions. I want to show that $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a weak Lyapunov function for the system

$$\begin{cases}
x'=y\\
y'=-x-y^3(1-x^2)^2
\end{cases}$$

So my solution so far is that calculation of $$\nabla V \cdot f= -2y^4(1-x^2)^2$$ for which I want to show that $-2y^4(1-x^2)^2 \leq 0$.

However, to me this looks like a strong Lyapunov function, since $(0,0)$ is not a point of interest, and it is positive if we look at every other point, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a strong Lyapunov function, since $\nabla V \cdot f$ equals zero along the whole line $y=0$ (which implies that there is no punctured neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ where it's less than zero).

Comment: When it comes to this context, what does the word strong mean? This is a term I have never heard before.

Comment: @CroCo: It's the same thing as just saying that $V$ is a Lyapunov function. That is, $V$ is a strong Lyapunov function (for the given system and some given equilibrium point $x^*$), in some open set $\Omega$ containing $x^*$, if $V(x^*)=0$, $V(x)>0$ for all $x \in \Omega \setminus \{ x^* \}$ and $\dot V(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \Omega \setminus \{ x^* \}$. It's just for contrast to the case of weak Lyapunov functions, where the last condition is relaxed to $\dot V \le 0$.

Comment: Okey, I understand! Thanks!